# Annotation of XML Schema in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb2

I'm working on an xml standard that requires that the following root element must be defined:

```
<ClinicalDocument xsi:schemaLocation=”urn:hl7 org:v3 CDA.xsd” xmlns=”urn:hl7-
org:v3” xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”>
```

Now, I'm using `java.xml.bind`. Usually I annotate each class and **then I use Marshallers and Unmarshallers to write/read valid xml files**.

"My idea" was to annotate the `package-info.java` to specify the `xsi:schemaLocation`, `xmlns` and `xmlns:xsi properties` of `ClinicalDocument`. However, I can only insert the last property (`xmlns:xsi`), while I have no idea of how to render the first and furthermore the second is rendered as `xmlns:ns3`.

Here is my code in `package-info.java`:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (                     
    xmlns = {
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="",
                   namespaceURI="urn:hl7-org:v3"),
        @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix="xsi",
                   namespaceURI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
    }
)
package foo;
```

Here is my class `ClinicalDocument.java` in package `foo`:

```
package foo;    

@XmlRootElement(name="ClinicalDocument")
public class ClinicalDocument {....}
```

And finally is what I get with the Marshaller:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns3="urn:hl7-org:v3">
...
</ClinicalDocument>
```

So, I have to create and read valid xml file under the three properties shown above. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried [XStream](xstream.codehaus.org) so far?

Comment: Really I didn't! Do you think it is better?

Comment: In order to serialize and deserialize objects to xml and vice versa, i don't know any framework which does it better. In addition it's very easy to use. Just give it a quick try! You'll see on the website whether it fits on your requirements or not.

Comment: @MKorsch I don't see how to configure that properties using XStream. Can you address myself to a specific online resource

Comment: For a simple serialization you dont need to configure nothing. Just look at the 2 minute tutorial for example. Ive alread pointed you to an online ressource: xstream.codehaus.org

Answer (score 0):

The only valid solution that I found is to add:

```
@XmlAttribute(name="xsi:schemaLocation")
protected final String xsi_schemaLocation="urn:hl7 org:v3 CDA.xsd"; 

@XmlAttribute(name="xmlns")
protected final String xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"; 

@XmlAttribute(name="xmlns:xsi")
protected final String xmlns_xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance";
```

in class `ClinicalDocument`.

It works, but I don't like it! I would like to use annotation at package level.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting the annotations is only the beginning of the requirements for reading and writing CDA documents - I would recommend the use of MDHT, open source project with an API to create, consume and validate CDA documents.

You can find the project here 
https://www.projects.openhealthtools.org/sf/projects/mdht/

Comment: Mhhh! Annotations is not required _di per se_ for CDA implementation. It is only an implementation technique. MDHT uses a proprietary format and only support conversion to/from cda2.

Comment: Yes MDHT currently only supports CDA R2 but MDHT is an open source project and is in no way using any proprietary format